# How to pipe spark rdd to python and return rdd back from the python

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pipe, rdd

Here is my code in scala file

```
val data = List("cdn.resized-images.covethome.com")
val dataRDD = sc.makeRDD(data)
val scriptPath = "/Users/hareshbhuriya/Documents/final-python-integration/web_domain_cleansing.py"
val result = dataRDD.pipe(scriptPath)
```

I am reading that string from python file using

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    output = sample_function(line)
    print(output)
```

here output from the python file is pandas dataFrame and I want to get it inside the scala file from where I have called the pipe function.

Instead of passing the `line` as a parameter to sample_function if I pass string directly as `cdn.resized-images.covethome.com` I am getting the output as desired.

Like this

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    output = sample_function("cdn.resized-images.covethome.com")
    print(output)
```

But I want to pass string dynamically. How should I handle/manipulate the string coming from sys.stdin ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

I required to use `line.rstrip()` then all works great. Thank you.